# Create tabs in Windows 8.1 Universal app

Tags: tabs, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 Universal app (using VS2013) and I would like to create tabs inside the `GridView`. After searching, I found tabs cannot be created so I need some solution where I can create something that at least looks like tabs.

Here s what I need:

I have images as tab headers. When I click on each image (like `Appbar` icon) different `StackPanel` should appear on the same grid.

This is how I need my app to look like:

[image: This is how I need my app to look like]

Comment: take a look at the hub control.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn449149.aspx

Comment: @KenTucker Thanks for that link, but im not sure how to get tab pivot through hub, 'cause i don't need navigation. I 've edited my question, please check the image link.

Comment: Here is a link to how could can simulate tabs  http://blog.davemdavis.net/2012/10/03/simulating-a-tab-control-in-a-windows-8-application/

Comment: @KenTucker Thanks, very helpful link!

Comment: @KenTucker This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

On phone, consider using the Pivot control. On desktop, there is no such control until you upgrade to Windows 10 UWP apps - where Pivot is present.

Otherwise, try this:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
            <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="Tab1State"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TabVisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="Tab1State">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Tab1Button.(ToggleButton.IsChecked)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="TabContent.SelectedItem" Value="{Binding ElementName=Tab1Content}"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Tab2State">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Tab2Button.(ToggleButton.IsChecked)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="TabContent.SelectedItem" Value="{Binding ElementName=Tab2Content}"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Tab3State">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Tab3Button.(ToggleButton.IsChecked)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="TabContent.SelectedItem" Value="{Binding ElementName=Tab3Content}"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">

        <!-- re-template radiobuttons as togglebuttons -->
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <RadioButton GroupName="TabButtons" x:Name="Tab1Button">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Checked">
                    <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="{Binding Name, ElementName=Tab1State}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red" />
                <TextBlock Margin="4,0" Text="Tab 1" />
            </StackPanel>
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton GroupName="TabButtons" x:Name="Tab2Button">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Checked">
                    <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="{Binding Name, ElementName=Tab2State}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Green" />
                <TextBlock Margin="4,0" Text="Tab2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton GroupName="TabButtons" x:Name="Tab3Button">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Checked">
                    <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="{Binding Name, ElementName=Tab3State}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Blue" />
                <TextBlock Margin="4,0" Text="Tab3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </RadioButton>

    </StackPanel>

    <FlipView x:Name="TabContent" Grid.Row="1">

        <!-- if the user changes the item through the flipview -->
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=TabContent}" Value="{Binding Name, ElementName=Tab1Content}">
                <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="{Binding Name, ElementName=Tab1State}"/>
            </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=TabContent}" Value="{Binding Name, ElementName=Tab2Content}">
                <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="{Binding Name, ElementName=Tab2State}"/>
            </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=TabContent}" Value="{Binding Name, ElementName=Tab3Content}">
                <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="{Binding Name, ElementName=Tab3State}"/>
            </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <Grid Background="Red" x:Name="Tab1Content">
            <!-- content -->
        </Grid>

        <Grid Background="Green" x:Name="Tab2Content">
            <!-- content -->
        </Grid>

        <Grid Background="Blue" x:Name="Tab3Content">
            <!-- content -->
        </Grid>

    </FlipView>


</Grid>
```

Be sure you reference the XAML Behaviors SDK.

Review the code. The trick is in the Visual States. You can update those to do anything you want, including updating multiple controls. Whatever you need.

Looks like this:

[image]

Best of luck!

Comment: I could not use this code unfortunately. I was unable to use `Setters` property for 'VisualState' .I'm not sure why.  @JerryNixon

Comment: Very sorry, @SamanvithaSuresh. Here I created a solution for Windows 8 and used Windows 10 XAML syntax. Sorry about that. You could update the Setter syntax with Storyboards. Or just copy the idea.

Comment: No problems, yes I used the idea and got results. Thanks again, @JerryNixon